Multiplication of long games
A short game is a finite game where each play in the game has only finitely many moves. Multiplication of surreal numbers is well defined, but it is not well defined on surreal games. Conway showed that each short game has a unique simplest form. This solves some of the multiplication of games problem, since I conjecture that multiplication of simple games is simple. This only leaves the finite long games, ie ones that still must terminate but may have infinitely many possible moves. I suspect that if they do not have a simplest form, which would be a largest/smallest element(s) in L/R, then they respect multiplication, but I am not sure on this as "On Numbers and Games" does not seem to talk about game multiplication or simplification of long games.
An example of this failing is with $\omega *$; if $\omega=\\\{0,1,2,3,... \mid\\\}$, then $\omega *=*_2$, but if $\omega=\\\{1,3,5,7,... \mid\\\}$, then $\omega *=0$. This means that in order for game multiplication to be well defined, a "canonical" game has to be set for each long game.

"Multiplication of surreal numbers is well defined," Are you sure ?

Surreal numbers, yes. Surreal games, no.

Since I would not say that this multiplication is well defined , it might be a good idea to present a multiplication and show this claim.

The surreal numbers are known to be a field, so saying that multiplication is well defined follows from that. What is an example of Conway multiplication not being well defined?

@Peter Could you elaborate on why you "would not say this multiplication is well defined"? The surreal numbers having arithmetic operations like multiplication is the sort of thing that's so uncontroversial that the Wikipedia page, and several textbooks ("On Numbers and Games", "Foundations of Analysis Over Surreal Number Fields", "Combinatorial Game Theory") and other papers and books ("An very brief overview of Surreal Numbers", "Surreal Numbers – An Introduction", the book "Surreal Numbers") all agree. Do you mean something subtle I'm missing?

For opfromthestart: 1. What do you mean by "Surreal games"? Just games? 2. What do you mean by "simple games" in the sentence "multiplication of simple games is simple"? 3. Most importantly, what is your question?

By surreal games I just meant games as by the syntax of Conway. Chapter 10 of ONAG is about simplifying short games, so a "simple game" is a game that cannot be simplified further. My question is: is there is a way to simplify games that are not short games, to allow multiplication of them to be well defined? And moreso, is there a way to do it (at least for games of countable birthday) that does not require the axiom of choice?

It may also require a "simple" multiplication, in that if $ab=c$ and a,b,c are simple, then $a *_s b := c$.

What you call a "simple (short) game" would usually be called "a (short) game in canonical form".

Kind of as an aside, is there any intuitive way of describing how the Conway multiplication of two games relates to the multiplicands?

@opfromthestart If you mean intuitive motivation for the formula, I think that might've been asked here before or is in a standard text. I have an answer in mind but would prefer not to answer every question that comes to mind in a comment. I recommend you work through select sections of Combinatorial Game Theory by Siegel and then come back to MathSE with any remaining questions.

I meant that, for example, what it means for star*star=star, is not clear. However I agree I should make a new post about that instead of asking it here.


My question is: is there is a way to simplify games that are not short games, to allow multiplication of them to be well defined?

If by "well defined", you mean that you take two literal games and get a unique game out: yes, the definition of multiplication in terms of options that you already know does that.
If by "well defined", you mean that you take two game values (equivalence classes of games under what the field unfortunately calls "equality" of games) and get a game value out: yes that works for (surreal) numbers (it's basically what I would call the definition of surreal multiplication), but no it doesn't work for (all) arbitrary games, as you observed.
If by "well defined", you mean that you take two game values and get a unique literal game out, then no (non-arbitrary one) because (as you observed in the question) there is no canonical/minimal form for a long game, even if it's a (surreal) number. I suppose you could do this with surreals in an arbitrary way via the axiom of choice.

Is there any equivalence relation on games that has been studied that is "between" form equality and value equality? eg $0=\{* \mid *}$ but $\{1,2,3,...\mid} \ne \{1,3,5,..\mid}$?

@opfromthestart Equality of impartial games under misere play sort of qualifies in that the first equation would be true but some other impartial equations would not be. And equality of partizan games under misere play is even finer, but again not what you're looking for.

Ok, I skipped that chapter when reading through so I will see if I can get anywhere with that.
